# Is "If a | bc, then a | b or a | c" valid?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I know this is statement is false and only correct for prime numbers. However, before I found the obvious counter examples I wrote a proof by contradiction and I cannot find the error I made. My proof is as follows:

a, b, c are integers and a is not $0$

Negation: $a | bc$ and $(a \nmid b$ and $a \nmid c)$

From the left side I know
 $bc\mod a = 0$

From the right side I can tell $b\mod a \neq 0$ and $c \mod a \neq 0$
so $bc \mod a \neq 0$ because if $a$ doesn't divide $b$ or $c$, then it won't divide any multiple of $b$ or $c$.

Now I have a contradiction. I have not been able to find my error, although the original statement is obviously false.

Comment: Putting in modular language just restates the problem.  The fact is that, if $n$ is not prime, there are non-trivial zero divisors $\pmod n$.  like $2\times 3\equiv 0 \pmod 6$.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  $bc\bmod a\ne0$ means $a\nmid bc$.  $4\nmid2,6$ but $4|2\times6$

Comment: "if b and c don't divide a, then no multiple of them will." Who said anything about b or c dividing a?

Comment: If $a = bc$ you don't have $a \mid b$ or $a \mid c$ either, right?

Comment: Yes I meant if a doesn't divide b or c, thank you for pointing that out. Your responses have clarified my question. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your final step. If $b$ and $c$ don't divide $a$, it is still possible for their product to divide $a$! In fact, this is a restatement of the very theorem you are trying to prove (written in terms of modular arithmetic instead of division).

As the comments have mentioned, $4 \not \mid 2$ and $4 \not \mid 6$, but $4 \mid 12$.
This is the same as saying $2$ and $6$ are not $0$ mod $4$, yet their product $12$ *is* $0$ mod $4$.

---

Hope this helps ^_^